# Trying to send web request in swift (IOS)

Tags: ios, swift, http-post

I looked up how to send a request, and found the answer on here, but while it seems to work for everyone else, it won't for me. Can some please please help me get the code to actually send the POST request, and print the response. The URL works, because I can manually enter in the information via my borwser, but it is a LAN website, but this app is just for learning SWIFT.

```
import UIKit
class PostController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func sendPost(url:String,attrs:String) {
    print("YO BOY")
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = attrs
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    print("NABBBADABBA")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }
        print("CHIKKA CHIKKA")
        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
        }
        print("FLEKKA FLEEKA WAHAPPA")
        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
    }
    task.resume()
}

@IBOutlet var text: UITextView!
@IBAction func post(_ sender: Any) {
    print("SENDING POST")
    sendPost(url: "localhost/testingtest.php",attrs: "post=\(text.text)")
}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}
`

my problem is happening somewhere here

```html
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }
```

with the terminal saying:

```html
SENDING POST
YO BOY
NABBBADABBA
2017-07-29 20:53:08.644 SocialMe[71829:3715670] -[SocialMe.PostController takePhoto:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f850bf092e0
2017-07-29 20:53:08.647 SocialMe[71829:3715670] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SocialMe.PostController takePhoto:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f850bf092e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001040c7b0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010136d141 objc_exception_throw + 48
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104137134 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
 3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010404e840 ___forwarding___ + 1024
 4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010404e3b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
 5   UIKit                               0x0000000101840d82 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
 6   UIKit                               0x00000001019c55ac -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
 7   UIKit                               0x00000001019c58c7 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
 8   UIKit                               0x00000001019c4802 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 618
 9   UIKit                               0x00000001018ae7ea -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2707
 10  UIKit                               0x00000001018aff00 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4114
 11  UIKit                               0x000000010185ca84 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
 12  UIKit                               0x00000001020405d4 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2926
 13  UIKit                               0x0000000102038532 __handleEventQueue + 1122
 14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010406dc01 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
 15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001040530cf __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 527
 16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001040525ff __CFRunLoopRun + 911
 17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104052016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
 18  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000105fd2a24 GSEventRunModal + 62
 19  UIKit                               0x000000010183f134 UIApplicationMain + 159
 20  SocialMe                            0x0000000100d8f957 main + 55
 21  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010506765d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: The error message is suggesting that it happened when iOS system tried to send a message with Selector `takePhoto:`. This often occurs when your storyboard is in sort of inconsistent state. Remove all connections of your `post` button and reconnect its action to the IBAction `post(_:)`.

Comment: I can't find anything in any of my swift files with 'takePhoto:'. I used Command+f to find it, but no results anywhere. I'm really new to Swift, and I'm really confused as to what to do. That view-controller is really the only thing with code that is run in it.

Comment: I assume you use Xcode and you have Main.storyboard in your project. You may have edited your storyboard file like putting a `post` button. I'm saying to check your **storyboard** files, not your swift files.

Comment: Okay. I removed the link from the button to any scripts, then relinked it to it's action, but the same error happens. I also tried changing the function from '_ sender: Any' to '_:' like your message example, but it gave an error. Like I said, I've been trying to learn Swift, but I am still like level 0 noob.

Comment: @EthanManzi try using Cmd+Shift+f and make sure that it says "In Workspace" right under the search input - it will look your entire project for given input.

Comment: @DaniyarKarbayev I used that, and removed the only 'takePhoto' showing up, but still to no avail.

Comment: @EthanManzi are getting exactly the same error?

Comment: @EthanManzi, If you get the same error message including `takePhoto:`, you have not removed the connection correctly. Have you checked a proper entry in the Xcode Help? And `post(_:)` is a notation for designating methods in Swift, which is not the method header. I believe I have never said you need to modify your Swift code.

Comment: @DaniyarKarbayev yes. Or at least as I can see. Everything appears simpler, and the actual error message is defiantly the same.

Comment: Okay, it isn't there. Sorry, i honestly didn't even see where you originally saw the takePhoto thing. Yes it now says "2017-07-29 22:04:29.549 SocialMe[73378:3805321] -[SocialMe.PostController post:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa8b0608540"

Comment: @EthanManzi if you're binding `post:` action to a UIButton then please make sure that you don't have previous connections left at "Show the Connections Inspector" right pane (you can select your button and press Cmd+Alt+6 to switch to it).

Comment: Thank you! That worked. The only problem now is with my websites certificate being 'invalid'. Thank you so much. :) @DaniyarKarbayev

Comment: @DaniyarKarbayev it sent a request, but theirs no content to the POST variable, all my SQL entries by the app are blank.

Comment: @EthanManzi could you please clarify: is your POST request empty on server side or is it the response to it that's empty?

Comment: @DaniyarKarbayev if I understand you, then my post request is empty. The web server is reached, but no data is actually sent, leaving empty table entries.